# Shell script - Smart replace in file with lookup in second file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have two files, one data file and one lookup file.

One field of the data file must be altered by a value, which can be found in the lookup file.

The datafile looks like:

```
2013-04-24;1;0.1635;1.4135
2013-04-24;1;0.9135;1.4135
2013-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135
```

The lookup file looks like:

```
1;2ab1e4c0-de4d-11e2-a934-0f0479162b1b
2;2ab21e90-de4d-11e2-9ce8-d368d9512bad
3;2ab2582e-de4d-11e2-bb5f-6b1f6c4437f8
```

The result must be:

```
2013-04-24 2ab1e4c0-de4d-11e2-a934-0f0479162b1b 0.1635 1.4135
2013-04-24 2ab1e4c0-de4d-11e2-a934-0f0479162b1b 0.9135 1.4135
2013-04-24 2ab21e90-de4d-11e2-9ce8-d368d9512bad 0.9135 1.4135
```

I know how to use awk to read the data file and transform the field seperator.

```
    awk 'BEGIN { FS = ";"; OFS = " " } ;
        {  print $1, $2, #3, $4 }' $1 > $1.updated
```

But I don't know a smart way to lookup variable $2 in the lookup file in shell script and replace the original value with the UUID.

The lookup file will never be large, in extreme situations there will be a maximum of 1000 records.

Any solution in bash or perl would be appreciated too.

Comment: Just FYI, your result is incorrect. Your data file has `2` as the third row which is replaced by value of `3` from lookup file.

Comment: You're right. I edited to not confuse further readers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{$2=a[$2]}1' lookup data
```

- Set the input field separator to `;`
- Run through lookup file, creating an array `a` with key of column 1 and storing column 2 as value
- Once look up file is loaded in memory, substitute the second column of data file with array value.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. I knew awk was very powerful, but this is really small code. Great!

Answer (score 2):

This is what `join` is for, although it does require the two input files to be sorted on the field you want to match on:

```
sort -t\; -k2,2 datafile.txt > datafile.tmp
sort -t\; -k1,1 lookup.txt > lookup.tmp
join -t\; -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1,2.2,1.3,1.4 datafile.tmp lookup.tmp | tr ';' ' '
```

If you're using `bash`, you could combine that all into one line and skip the temporary files:

```
join -t\; -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1,2.2,1.3,1.4 <(sort -t\; -k2,2 datafile.txt) <(sort -t\; -k1,1 lookup.txt) | tr ';' ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` has "arrays" (which actually function like hashes/dictionaries) that work quite well for this.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = ";"; OFS = " " }
     {
         if (NR == FNR)
             values[$1] = $2
         else
             print $1, values[$2], $3, $4
     }' lookup data
```

Comment: It's bad practice in software to test a condition (e.g. `NR==FNR`) and then test the negation of that same condition (`NR!=FNR`). Just use `next` or, less preferably in this case, code an if-else.

Comment: Great point; just because it's `awk` doesn't mean you should ignore best practices. I edited the code per your advice. (I used an if-else because there's already an answer with a `next` and a conditional   might be easier for a person new to `awk` to understand.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an all Bash solution.

```
while IFS=\; read _ stored; do
    string+=($stored)
done < lookup_file
ref=0
while IFS=\; read date _ data1 data2; do
    echo $date ${string[$ref]} $data1 $data2
    ((ref++))
done < data_file
```

This stores the targeted strings from the lookup file in an array and references them as it reads from the data file.