# Why do I get blanks on some rows when using shell script to replace in file with lookup in second file?

Tags: shell, awk, replace, lookup

I have one file data.txt with content

```
2013-04-24;1;0.1635;1.4135;fp.3.Luci_02C06.ctg.ctg7180000085546
2013-04-24;1;0.9135;1.4135;fp.3.Luci_01A01.ctg.ctg7180000038386
2017-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;fp.3.Luci_02C06.ctg.ctg7180000085546
2011-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;fp.3.Luci_02C06.ctg.ctg7180000085546
2012-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;fp.3.Luci_02C06.ctg.ctg7180000085549
2016-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;fp.3.Luci_02C06.ctg.ctg7180000085549
2016-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4335;fp.3.Luci_02C06.ctg.ctg7180000085549
2013-04-24;1;0.9135;1.4135;fp.3.Luci_01A01.ctg.ctg7180000038386
2011-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;fp.3.Luci_02C06.ctg.ctg7180000085546
```

and another file lookup.txt with content

```
1;2012-04-24;2ab1e4c0-de4d-11e2-a934-0f0479162b1b;fp.3.Luci_02C06.ctg.ctg7180000085546
7;2013-04-24;2ab21e90-de4d-11e2-9ce8-d368d9512bad;fp.3.Luci_01A01.ctg.ctg7180000038386
3;2014-04-24;2ab2582e-de4d-11e2-bb5f-6b1f6c4437f8;fp.3.Luci_02C06.ctg.ctg7180000085549
```

I want to replace column 5 in data.txt with column 1 in lookup.txt based on matching values in column 4 in lookup.txt. The result  I want is

```
2013-04-24;1;0.1635;1.4135;1
2013-04-24;1;0.9135;1.4135;7
2017-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;1
2011-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;1
2012-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;3
2016-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;3
2016-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4335;3
2013-04-24;1;0.9135;1.4135;7
2011-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;1
```

I [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22253586/5733571) I found the following shell script which looks promising

`awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{a[$4]=$1;next}{$5=a[$5]}1' lookup.txt data.txt`

But the result below leaves for some reason column 5 blank for row 5,6,7 and 9. Why? The fact that we get space separators rather than ";" is also an issue but not as important

```
2013-04-24 1 0.1635 1.4135 1
2013-04-24 1 0.9135 1.4135 7
2017-04-24 2 0.9135 1.4135 1
2011-04-24 2 0.9135 1.4135 1
2012-04-24 2 0.9135 1.4135
2016-04-24 2 0.9135 1.4135
2016-04-24 2 0.9135 1.4335
2013-04-24 1 0.9135 1.4135 7
2011-04-24 2 0.9135 1.4135
```

Comment: Check that `lookup.txt` has unix line-endings and not dos or mac

Comment: To fix the output separator, set `OFS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```sh
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}
{
   sub(/\r$/, "")
} 
NR == FNR {
   map[$NF] = $1
   next
}
{
   $NF = map[$NF]
} 1' lookup.txt data.txt

2013-04-24;1;0.1635;1.4135;1
2013-04-24;1;0.9135;1.4135;7
2017-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;1
2011-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;1
2012-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;3
2016-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;3
2016-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4335;3
2013-04-24;1;0.9135;1.4135;7
2011-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;1
```

**Explanation:**

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}`: Sets input and output field delimiters to `;`
- Use `NF` consistently instead of numbered column in both files
- `sub(/\r$/, "")` is to remove any carriage characters from line end

Comment: This solved the problem with the seperators and jhnc solved, in comment to my question, the problem with blank rows.

Comment: Yes, I have added `sub(/\r$/, "")` to remove `\r` (if present)

Answer (score -1):

By nullifying `NF` at the `FNR==NR` step, it has the same effect as explicitly using `next` statement.

If you're very certain the replacement values are never zero, then the final condition can be simplified to just `$NF = __[$NF]`

```
mawk 'FNR==NR { NF=_*(__[$NF]=$!_) }_!~($NF=__[$NF])' RS='[\r]?[\n]' 
                                                   FS=';'
                                                  OFS=';' test_lookup_0005.txt 
                                                          test_data_0005.txt

2013-04-24;1;0.1635;1.4135;1
2013-04-24;1;0.9135;1.4135;7
2017-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;1
2011-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;1
2012-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;3
2016-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;3
2016-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4335;3
2013-04-24;1;0.9135;1.4135;7
2011-04-24;2;0.9135;1.4135;1
```